# Remove duplicates on column based in apache beam java sdk

Tags: java, apache-beam, apache-beam-io, apache-beam-internals

How do I remove multiple occurrences of row based on `SessionId` in apache beam java skd.
I have tried with `Distinct` as well as `Deduplicate` but that takes entire row based and removes.

```
import org.apache.beam.sdk.io.TextIO;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.Distinct;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.values.PCollection;

public class DistinctExample {
    
    public static void main(String[] s) {
        Pipeline p = Pipeline.create();
        PCollection<String> input = p.apply(TextIO.read().from("C:\\ApacheBeam\\Beam\\distinct\\user.csv"));
        PCollection<String> unique = input.apply(Distinct.<String>create());
        unique.apply(TextIO.write().to("C:\\ApacheBeam\\Beam\\distinct\\dis_user.csv").withNumShards(1).withSuffix(".csv"));
        p.run();
    }

}
```

`user.csv` as below

````
SessionId,UserId,UserName,VideoId,Duration,StartTime,Gender,Phone
1001,1,James,1,500,2011-11-11T10:00:00Z,M,1111111111
1002,2,Leena,2,500,2011-11-12T10:00:00Z,F,1111111112
1003,3,James,2,1500,2011-12-12T10:00:00Z,M,11111113
1004,3,James,2,1500,2011-12-12T10:00:00Z,,1111111114
1005,3,James,2,1500,2011-12-12T10:00:00Z,O,1111111115
1005,3,abcd,2,1500,2011-12-12T10:00:00Z,O,1111111116
1004,3,def,2,1500,2011-12-12T10:00:00Z,,1111111117


Expected output
SessionId,UserId,UserName,VideoId,Duration,StartTime,Gender,Phone
1001,1,James,1,500,2011-11-11T10:00:00Z,M,1111111111
1002,2,Leena,2,500,2011-11-12T10:00:00Z,F,1111111112
1003,3,James,2,1500,2011-12-12T10:00:00Z,M,11111113```
````

Comment: Does your separator "," mean another column content?

Comment: I mean if any ```SessionId``` is repeated then that row needs to be dropped and yes separator is ","

Comment: So, why the rows with SessionId's 1004 and 1005 are dropped too in your expected results ?

Comment: I dont want ```SessionId's`` that are duplicated

Answer (score 3):

By default, `Distinct` transform uses the whole input element (row) for comparison. So, if you need to filter the duplicates based only on specific column, then you have to use `Distinct.withRepresentativeValueFn(SerializableFunction)` and provide a function that maps each element to a representative value.

Comment: Hey @Alexey,
can you please share an example for the SerializableFunction in this case